# Need to Delete old row from my table on conflict of the particular column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Spec: Postgresql 9.5
      Python3.5
      psycopg2

I have table(dummy) column1, column2, column3, column4 & column5. if i have on conflict with column2 which contains phone number i need to delete the entire row(old entry).

master table needs both rows. so i have cloned the dummy table.

**Data are injected through python from copying external csv file**

UPSERT options works only on injection level?

[image]

Insertion only happens on "Master Table" through copying CSV.

How to check on Master_dummy after copied?

Comment: Welcome to DAB stack exchange, may you please provide more details and example. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a before trigger and a function, so when you insert a record the trigger will attempt to delete any record that is already in the table that matches your column2 before the insert is attempted.

```
CREATE FUNCTION DeleteOldRecords() RETURNS trigger AS $DeleteOldRecords$
    BEGIN
        Delete From table
        Where table.column2 = NEW.column2

        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$DeleteOldRecords$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER ExampleTrigger 
BEFORE INSERT ON table
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE DeleteOldRecords();
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: Please post valid syntax.  Also, I think the official documentation is a way better source than tutorialspoint.

Comment: Updated, Fixed both things

Comment: Insertion only happens on "Master Table" through copying CSV.

How to check on Master_dummy after copied?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG3Rj.jpg

Comment: con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='DND' user='postgres' password='Admin@123'")   
cur = con.cursor()


def OpenFile():


 name = askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/Desktop/",filetypes =(("All Files","*.*"),("Text File", "*.txt")),title = "Choose a file.")
 
 print(name) 
 
 copy_sql = """
           COPY dndschema.master FROM stdin WITH CSV HEADER
           DELIMITER as ','
           """
 
 try:
  
  out1.config(text = name)
  with open(name, 'r') as f:
      cur.copy_expert(sql=copy_sql, file=f)
    
  con.commit()
 cur.close()

Comment: Why not just add a datetime column to the master table and point the view to the master table and use the datetime to get the most recent versions of the records?

Comment: You need  a `;` at the end of this line `Where table.column2 = NEW.column2`